# Search then loop through files that were uploaded via FTP

Tags: templating, assets, search, forloop, loop

Is it possible to search a server folder containing image and video files that were previously uploaded via ftp and then loop through those files in the entry template?

Each entry has a unique Log ID number field which is also part of the image or video filename.

Example:

- Log ID: **12345**
- Image filename: **12345**-[8374]-img-01.jpg
- Image filename: **12345**-[8374]-img-02.jpg
- Video filename: **12345**-[8374]-vid-01.mp4
- etc...

Conceptually on the template page...

- Grab the entry LogID field (ex. "12345")
- Search the media server folder for all filenames that begin with the LogID
- Display all of the found images and videos

I found [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/auto-add-images-to-entry-after-ftp-to-server) which is very similar but I don't have the skills to write a plugin.

Comment: Any reason you couldn't Settings->Tools->Update Asset Indexes after every FTP upload and deal with the uploads as proper Craft Assets?

Comment: @BradBell do you mean then open each entry and attach the uploads? If that's what you mean, I could, but we upload about 200 files every week for about 50 preexisting entries.  I was hoping that there may be another way to do it automatically.

Comment: Well... there is, but it's going to require a plugin. :)  I can't think of any other way.

Comment: @BradBell I wonder if I misunderstood your initial suggestion about using "Update Asset Indexes" tool. If I index the files so they exist in the database, they can be searched, correct? So in my template, could I grab the LogID field value from the page entry and then used that value to search the assets folder for filenames that contain that LogID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out a solution thanks to Brad's suggestion to update the asset indexes. That allowed me to find all assets on the server that contained a partial match to my LogID number which I am passing in a URL string.